# PHP POST not receiving selected options

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to post a simple `select` with the `multiple` attribute:

```
<select name="cboCategory[]" id="cboCategory" class="box" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="18">Cookies</option>
    <option value="19">Cookie Bouquets</option>
    <option value="20">Cookie Platters</option>
    <option value="21">Cookie Pizzas</option>
    <option value="22">Cakes</option>
    <option value="23">Cupcakes</option>
    <option value="25">Gifts - Corporate</option>
    <option value="26">Gifts - Misc.</option>
    <option value="27">â€¢ Birthday</option>
    <option value="28">â€¢ Baby</option>
    <option value="29">â€¢ Get Well</option>
    <option value="30">â€¢ Congratulations</option>
    <option value="31">â€¢ Thank You</option>
    <option value="35">â€¢ Holiday</option>
    <option value="41">Gifts</option>
    <option value="42">&nbsp;&nbsp;Corporate</option>
    <option value="43">&nbsp;&nbsp;Miscellaneous</option>
</select>
```

On the PHP side, I'm just trying to print out the selected values:

```
var_dump( $_POST['cboCategory'] ); exit;
```

When I have it set up this way, the output is always `string(0) ""`. It just won't pass any of the selected options.

However, if I remove the brackets from the select name, changing it to `name="cboCategory"` it works fine, returning only one of the selected values.

Can anyone else figure out why I can't get this to work? I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

**EDIT:** Here's the entire `$_POST` variable:

```
array(15) { ["cboCategory"]=> string(0) "" ["txtName"]=> string(28) "50th Birthday Cookie Bouquet" ["mtxDescription"]=> string(266) "Half a decade is a big deal! Celebrate it with one of our cookie bouquets. They are overflowing with our delicious homemade large cookies on a stick, balloon on a stick, large candy bar, candy bites, ribbons, decorations, and your enclosure card. Container may vary." ["txtOptionName"]=> string(7) "default" ["txtValue1"]=> string(9) "4 cookies" ["txtPrice1"]=> string(2) "25" ["txtValue2"]=> string(9) "6 cookies" ["txtPrice2"]=> string(2) "30" ["txtValue3"]=> string(9) "8 cookies" ["txtPrice3"]=> string(2) "35" ["txtValue4"]=> string(0) "" ["txtPrice4"]=> string(0) "" ["txtValue5"]=> string(0) "" ["txtPrice5"]=> string(0) "" ["txtQty"]=> string(4) "4999" }
```

**EDIT2:** Thanks for all the help everyone. I found the issue, it was indeed outside of what I had posted. I had my `var_dump` at the top of the page, and the post was working fine without the brackets, so I had assumed everything else was set up correctly. However, there were a couple includes before my var_dump, and there was something in one of the includes ruining arrays in `$_POST`.

Comment: use $_POST['cboCategory[]'] instead

Comment: Please show the rest of the code surrounding this as the entire form declaration is relevant not just the one element.

Comment: debugging 101: if a specific post var is not found, check if your post works at all using `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I've doubled checked that the value is being posted by using `var_dump($_POST)` already. Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I'll edit my question with the output.

Comment: try multiple="yes" rather than multiple="multpile" that's how i have mine set up and it works

Comment: Do you have more than 1 element with the same name?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Tried `multiple="yes"`, no dice. :(

Comment: can you post the rest of the form? i don't see anything wrong with the select box itself. a bit more of the surrounding php code might help too.

Comment: @brunoais There are no other elements in that form named "cboCategory"

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone. I got it figured out.

Comment: @Jimmy: just curious - what was the issue?

Comment: @satya: php uses `[]` in a field names to signify creating an ARRAY of values. the `[]` would normally never appear in $_POST.

Comment: @Raidenace There was a little bit of code in an included script which was attempting to perform "magic_quotes" on every value in $_POST, but it didn't take arrays into consideration, so the array was just getting flattened.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your code. You should ensure that you have placed your select box inside the form tag, that at least one element is selected and that there are no other elements in the form tag with the same name.

Checklist:

1. Select box is inside form tag
2. Does not have another element with same name inside same form
3. At least one element is selected in select box

Answer (score 0):

Is that selectBox inside the form you are submitting?

Is that form submitting with action="post" ?

Comment: Yes and yes. If I run `var_dump($_POST);`, it includes `cboCategory`, but its value is still just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

in php

```
foreach($_POST['cboCategory'] as $category)
{

echo $category . "<br>";

}
```

what christian said is not right

Sure you're not using get instead of post on the form's method attribute?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) does a better job than that.

Comment: regardless of efficiency, if one doesn't work, the other won't either. the issue is that the values aren't getting into his php array